# I have a vector that has pointers to elements from 2 subtypes accessed via an interface. Can't seem to re-arrange the vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a really over engineered matrix calculator for school and hit a brick wall with the very last function I need. The full version of the `transpose()` is supposed to re-arrange my matrix and to switch columns and rows around.

I posted this question earlier with a snippet but was asked to write a minimum reproducable sample. This isn't very "minimum" but I tried.

So. I have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>>` that can hold objects of types `Sub1` and `Sub2`.

In the full version I have a class that bypasses `Interface` and works fine since it only holds `Sub2` objects.

However I can't seem to get it to work when there are multiple types in the vector. Nothing I've tried in the past few hours has done anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>


//this is the one that won't work
Super Super::transpose() const {
    Super newMatrix = *this;
    int i = 1;
    for(auto& elem : elements){
        *elem = *newMatrix.elements[i];
        i--;
    }
return *this;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> newMatrix;
    newMatrix.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Sub1>(new Sub1('x')));
    newMatrix.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Sub2>(new Sub2(1)));
    Super mtx(std::move(newMatrix),2 );
    std::cout << mtx << std::endl;
    mtx.transpose();
    std::cout << mtx;
    return 0;
}

//busywork from here on 
Super::Super(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> matrix, int pN){
    elements = std::move(matrix);
    n = pN;
}

std::unique_ptr<Interface> Sub1::clone() const {
    char newVal = val;
    return std::unique_ptr<Sub1>(new Sub1(newVal));
}

std::unique_ptr<Interface> Sub2::clone() const {
    int newVal = i;
    return std::unique_ptr<Sub2>(new Sub2(newVal));
}

Sub1::Sub1(char pVal) {
    val = pVal;
}

Sub2::Sub2(int pI) {
    i = pI;
}

std::string Sub1::toString() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << val;
    return ss.str();
}

std::string Sub2::toString() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    return ss.str();
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Super &matrix) {
    os << "[";
    int i = 0;
    for (auto &elem : matrix.elements) {
        os << elem->toString();
        if (i < matrix.n - 1) {
            os << ",";
        }
        i++;
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}

Super::Super(const Super &matrix) {
    n = matrix.n;
    for (auto &elem : matrix.elements) {
        std::unique_ptr<Interface> newElem = elem->clone();
        elements.push_back(std::move(newElem));
    }
}
```

And heres the header

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_MAIN_H
#define EXAMPLE_MAIN_H

#include <memory>
#include <vector>


class Interface{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Interface> clone() const = 0;
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};

class Super{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> elements;
    int n = 2;
public:
    Super(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> elements, int n);
    Super(const Super &matrix);
    Super transpose() const;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Super &matrix);
};

class Sub1: public Interface{
private:
    char val;
public:
    Sub1(char pVal);
    std::string toString() const override;
    std::unique_ptr<Interface> clone() const override;
};


class Sub2: public Interface{
private:
    int i;
public:
    Sub2(int pI);
    std::string toString() const override;
    std::unique_ptr<Interface> clone() const override;
};


std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Super &matrix);

#endif //EXAMPLE_MAIN_H
```

Comment: `int i = 1;` and then decrementing `i` in `transpose` does not look right. And please explain what exactly is not working. This is easiest done by including input, output and expected output

Comment: Yeah the i--; thing was just to quickly switch the 2 values around. In the elements vector of the current instance. For the demo. In this example I just want the elements behind the pointers in [0] and [1] to change places.

Comment: Or the values rather. not elements.

Comment: When i run it the output should be [x,1] [1,x], not [x,1] [x,1].

Answer (score 2):

> `Super Super::transpose() const;`

This looks like a function that shouldn't change `*this` when called, but should return a transposed version of `*this`.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>

Super Super::transpose() const {
    Super newMatrix = *this;
    std::reverse(newMatrix.elements.begin(), newMatrix.elements.end());
    return newMatrix;
}
```

If you'd like to transpose `*this` in-place, change it to:

> `Super& Super::transpose();`

```
Super& Super::transpose() {
    std::reverse(elements.begin(), elements.end());
    return *this;
}
```

If you *must* create a temporary object first, you can, but you can't assign a dereferenced `Interface*` to another dereferenced `Interface*`. Moving the `unique_ptr` works though:

```
Super& Super::transpose() {
    Super newMatrix = *this;
    size_t s = elements.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
        elements[i] = std::move(newMatrix.elements[s - i - 1]);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/seWWUF)

You can also encapsulate the `std::unique_ptr<Interface>` in a wrapper class to add a copy constructor and assignment operator (which is not supported by `std::unique_ptr`). By doing that, you can greatly simplify your other classes. Your `Super` class wouldn't need to know anything about cloning. Copying/moving elements would work out-of-the-box.

Example wrapper:

```
class Cell {
public:
    Cell() noexcept = default;                              // empty Cell ctor
    explicit Cell(std::unique_ptr<Interface>&& d) noexcept; // converting ctor

    // rule of five
    Cell(const Cell& rhs);                           // must be implemented
    Cell(Cell&& rhs) noexcept = default;             // handled by unique_ptr
    Cell& operator=(const Cell& rhs);                // must be implemented
    Cell& operator=(Cell&& rhs) noexcept = default;  // handled by unique_ptr
    ~Cell() = default;                               // handled by unique_ptr

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept; // proxy for unique_ptr operator bool
    void reset() noexcept;                   // empty the Cell

    // dereferencing
    Interface& operator*();
    const Interface& operator*() const;
    Interface* operator->();
    const Interface* operator->() const;

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const;     // calls: os << data->toString()

    // A helper factory to make a Cell of a certain type using the converting ctor
    template<typename T, class... Args>
    static Cell make(Args&&... args) {
        return Cell(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Interface> data{};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Cell& c); // calls c.print(os)
```

The copy constructor and copy assignment operator can be implemented like this:

```
Cell::Cell(const Cell& rhs) : data(rhs ? rhs.data->clone() : nullptr) {}

Cell& Cell::operator=(const Cell& rhs) {
    if(this != &rhs) data = rhs ? rhs.data->clone() : nullptr;
    return *this;
}
```

Here's a [demo with a 2D matrix](https://godbolt.org/z/nVFgAz) using a `std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>`. Such 2D vectors are not very effective but it serves the purpose of the demo.

Comment: thanks. this got me on the right track, but i had to modify it slightly to fit my usecase in the actual program so i came up with something much less elegant.

Comment: I see. Well, you don't need to make two copies of `*this` - and if you'd like to transpose in-place, it's certainly possible. I edited my answer. I also added a lot to the demo, like cloning by using the copy constructors of the subclasses etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Interface` has no virtual assignment operator, so naturally `*elem = newMatrix.elements[i];` will not work. I think `elem = std::move(newMatrix.elements[i]));` should do what you want.

Edit: Sorry, `Interface` will have a assignment operator, since that will be default created. But it won't be virtual, so the assignment on `Interface` will do pretty much nothing, since it doesn't call the assignment operators for the child classes. You could write those all, but it seems not really worth the effort.

Comment: Neither works even after Implementing the all the same assingment overloads that are specified in the UML for my full project. ```Super &operator=(const Super &matrix)```, ```Super &operator=(Super &&matrix)``` and ```Super(Super &&matrix)```

Comment: You can't really do it by assignment operator in the element classes, since those can never change the type of the objects. The `unique_ptr`s need to be given pointers to objects with the correct most-derived types, whether initially or by assignment to the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this hideous thing to fix it. I'd have liked it to to transpose the matrix nicely in it's place but it looks like it isn's happening tonight. So instead im creating a new object.

```
Super::Super(Super &&matrix) {
   elements = std::move(matrix.elements);
   n = matrix.n;
}

//this was the one that wouldn't work
Super Super::transpose() const {
    Super newMatrix = *this;
    Super anotherOne = *this;
    anotherOne.elements.clear();
    for(int i = 1; i > -1; i--){
        anotherOne.elements.push_back(std::move(newMatrix.elements[i]));
    }
    return anotherOne;
 }

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Interface>> newMatrix;
   newMatrix.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Sub1>(new Sub1('x')));
   newMatrix.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Sub2>(new Sub2(1)));
   Super mtx(std::move(newMatrix),2 );
   std::cout << mtx << std::endl;
   Super aa(std::move(mtx.transpose()));
   std::cout << aa;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: One quick improvement to this would be to avoid the initial clones in `anotherOne` which immediately get destroyed: `Super anotherOne{{}, n};` creates it with an initially empty `elements` in the first place. You could also do `anotherOne.elements.reserve(elements.size());` before the loop. Though I'd prefer the `std::reverse` ways in Ted's answer.

Comment: Yeah the reverse method would be nice if I didn't have to transpose N*N matrices. I should've left that in the question originally but I wanted to keep it as concise as I could. I'm just trying to get this thing done so I can sleep at this point. Haha.

Comment: @Stuge  It's hard to answer what's not in the question and I think the question, as it is, was answered. Nevertheless, I've updated my answer and added a full demo of a 2D matrix with functions to transpose.